# ZonedDateTime value incorrect after loading via Spring Boot JPA, PostgreSQL

Tags: java-time

I have a ZonedDateTime with a specific instant in time, with the Zone set to America/Los_Angeles.

If I display this using the pattern `"d-MMM-uuuu HH:mm VV"` it shows as I expect (e.g. ... 8:00 am America/Los_Angeles).

However, if I change the pattern very minimally by removing the "VV", then it does not show the time in west coast time, it shows it in my local time (east coast), or 11:00 am - so it essentially ignores the zone set on the ZonedDateTime and instead uses something else (I assume the system local zone).

I would prefer to not display the time zone id in some cases, to save space (in a table for instance), but still want it to be displayed in the local time.

Is there a way to do that?

Update:

I note that using the pattern `"d-MMM-uuuu HH:mm O"`, surprisingly, gives what I consider a wrong answer:

2-Jun-2020 11:09 GMT-7

here is the correct time, which shows using VV:

2-Jun-2020 08:09 America/Los_Angeles

The 11am value with "GMT-7" looks like it is clearly a bug - granted I am still using Java 8.

Update:

I think the problem may be in the data layer, though I am still trying to figure that out... (I am using Spring Boot JPA and PostgreSQL).

If I just purely use Java, as such:

```html
        ZoneId pdt = ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles");
        ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now().withZoneSameInstant(pdt);
        logger.debug("now with VV: "+now.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-MMM-uuuu HH:mm VV")));
        logger.debug("now with O: "+now.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-MMM-uuuu HH:mm O")));
        logger.debug("now with nothing: "+now.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-MMM-uuuu HH:mm")));
        logger.debug("now with VV+withZ: "+now.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-MMM-uuuu HH:mm VV").withZone(pdt)));
        logger.debug("now with O+withZ: "+now.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-MMM-uuuu HH:mm O").withZone(pdt)));
        logger.debug("now with nothing+withZ: "+now.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-MMM-uuuu HH:mm").withZone(pdt)));
        logger.debug("using static formatter: "+now.format(TIMESTAMP_FORMATTER_SHORT));
        logger.debug("using static formatter w/zone: "+now.format(TIMESTAMP_FORMATTER_SHORT.withZone(pdt)));
```

then in every case it shows the expected correct time in LA.

So, in debugging to see the differences, I see this anomaly:

In plain java if I look at the value of now (in code above), it looks correct - the LocalDateTime shows the current time in LA, and the offset is 7 hrs.

If I look at the ZonedDateTime value that is set after the JPA load, however, it looks unusual:

- the value stored in the DB has the hour at 15 (as expected, UTC time)
- the value in the LocalDateTime within the ZonedDateTime is off - it is showing the hour as 11, which is the local system time, not the time in LA
- however the ZonedDateTime offset is still -7

What is really odd about this is that somehow DateTimeFormatter corrects the problem, but *only when I use VV in the format*.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your code?

Comment: I have not been able to reproduce your problem in Java 8 or Java 14.  The same time of day is displayed regardless of whether the pattern has a timezone, for me.  Is it possible your ZonedDateTime values are not what you think they are?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the post with the latest info on what seems to be wrong with the ZonedDateTime - though I have no idea how it gets broken.

Answer (score 0):

I have determined the problem (not with JPA or PostgreSQL unsurprisingly).

Rather this is a bug that had been introduced a long time ago, but never exposed until I switched to trying to show a shorter display of the timestamp.

The code actually causing the problem was post processing a native query, incorrectly converting a java.sql.Timestamp into a ZonedDateTime.  Here is the problem code:

```
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = (Timestamp) objects[0];
String tzId = (String) objects[1];
ZonedDateTime dt = ZonedDateTime.of(timestamp.toLocalDateTime(), ZoneId.of(tzId));
```

I was incorrectly assuming that the ZonedDateTime.of would use the provided ZoneId to revise the time, but I believe that is not how it works.  Instead, the toLocalDateTime() was creating a LocalDateTime based on the system default, which therefore did not agree with the ZoneId value passed in, which was the value stored in the DB and not the same as the system default.

Here is how I corrected the code:

```
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = (Timestamp) objects[0];
String tzId = (String) objects[1];
ZonedDateTime dt = ZonedDateTime.of(timestamp.toLocalDateTime(), ZoneId.systemDefault())
                                        .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of(tzId));
```